# Numeric value in .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've searched a lot, but didn't find anything.

I am using codeigniter.
my current url is:
`base_url/content_controller/content_download/download_id`
but, I need to do it:
`base_url/download_id`

as download id is numeric, my .htaccess doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^download/content/2$ 2 [L]
```

Please tell me how to solve that and if there is any way to do it without .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jon,
I tried several times but multiple rule conflicts. So I do it in another way.
when I hit the URL http://www.example.com/2/ it shows Not Found.
So, I use 404 controller to handle the numeric value. Finally I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /download/content/$1 [L]
```

So if you request `http://example.com/123`, the URI will be rewritten to `/download/content/123`.

Comment: Thanks. but here it shows, Internal Server Error. My complete .htaccess is: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /download/content/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @Shuvo You should put the above rule before any of the rules you have in your htaccess file. You can't mix it inbetween some conditions, that will break everything.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried a lot, but couldn't make it happen. your RewriteERule and Codeigniter's RewriteRule is conflicting. your code works good. but I need to manage the htaccess in such way, that it can handle both codeigniter and numeric values.  my code for CI URL is:RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] please help me. Thanks.